# hibernate ElementCollection looks for wrong column

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to make a basic project editor for a university course. I have never used hibernate before so I have run in quite a few problems and this one has me stumped - there must be something I'm not understanding in the documentation.

When I try to load the list of activities within a project, I get this error:

```
Hibernate: select activities0_.Project_Id as Project_6_0_0_, activities0_.activities_Id as activiti8_0_0_, activity1_.Id as Id1_0_1_, activity1_.Description as Descript2_0_1_, activity1_.Duration as Duration3_0_1_, activity1_.End_Date as End_Date4_0_1_, activity1_.Name as Name5_0_1_, activity1_.Project_Id as Project_6_0_1_, activity1_.Start_Date as Start_Da7_0_1_ from Activities activities0_ inner join Activities activity1_ on activities0_.activities_Id=activity1_.Id where activities0_.Project_Id=?
18:40:44.775 [qtp94264799-20] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
18:40:44.776 [qtp94264799-20] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Unknown column 'activities0_.activities_Id' in 'field list'
```

which results in the session not closing properly, the data not being retreived and the whole program not working as intended.

The two classes involved are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Projects")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5115375190980452672L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Project_Id")
    private int id; // this should be set once on creation and never touched
                    // again as it identifies the project uniquely
    @Column(name = "Owner_Id")
    private int ownerId;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="Activities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Project_Id"))
    @Column(name="Activity")
    private List<Activity> activities;

    public Project(){

    }
    /**
     * Constructor to load existing project
     * @param idToLoad id of the project to load
     */
    public Project(int idToLoad) { 
//      MySqlDriver.loadObjectWithId(this, idToLoad);
        org.hibernate.Session session;
        try{
            session=Start.getFactory().getCurrentSession();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not load project.");
            System.out.println("Error while creating mysql session: "+e);
            return;
        }
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.load(this, idToLoad);
            this.activities.size();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not load project.");
            System.out.println("Error while committing changes: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates new project
     * @param newName name of the new project
     * @param newId id of the new project
     */
    public Project(String newName, int owner_Id) { // on creation a project
                                                        // only has a name and a
                                                        // unique id
        this.name = newName;
        this.ownerId = owner_Id;
        this.activities = null;
    }

    public void addActivity(String activityName) { // add new activity to the
                                                    // project with given
                                                    // attributes
        Activity newActivity = new Activity(activityName, this.id);
        this.activities.add(newActivity);
    }

    public void setName(String newName) { // change project name
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() { // return project name
        return this.name;
    }

    public List<Activity> getActivities(){
        return this.activities;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void commitChanges() {
        for (Activity act : this.activities)
            act.commitChanges(); // commit changes made to all activities in the
                                    // project
        MySqlDriver.saveObject(this);
    }

    public void deleteProject() {
        MySqlDriver.deleteObject(this);
    }

    public Activity selectActivity(String activityName) {
        for (Activity act : activities) { // cycle through activities and return
                                            // the one with the given name
            if (act.getName().equals(activityName))
                return act;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteActivity(String deleteMeName) {
        for (Activity act : activities) { // cycle through activities and delete
                                            // the one with the given name
            if (act.getName().equals(deleteMeName)) {
                MySqlDriver.deleteObject(act);
                activities.remove(act);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void grantAccessToProject(String otherUser) {
        // grants permission to view and modify project database to user
        // otherUser
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Activities")
public class Activity {

    private static final long minDateDiff = 3600000;    //1H in milliseconds

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;    //using same name for activities in same project not supported.
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="Start_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name="End_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDate;
    @Column(name="Duration")
    private long duration;
    @Column(name="Project_Id")
    private int parent;



    /**
     * Activity constructor, automatically sets default start and end date.
     * @param newName Name of the new activity
     * @param parent id of parent project
     */
    public Activity(String newName, int parent){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.name = newName;
        this.startDate = new Date();    //start date by default is creation time
        this.endDate = new Date();
        this.endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + Activity.minDateDiff);   //end date by default is 1 hour ahead of start date
        this.description = new String();
        this.getDateDiff(startDate, endDate, TimeUnit.HOURS);   //set default duration
    }

    public void getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {    //converts difference between dates from 
                                                                                //milliseconds to given time unit
                                                                            //credit to Sebastien Lorber (from StackOverflow)
        long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        this.duration=timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date newStartDate){
        Date dummyDate = new Date();
        if(newStartDate.getTime() > dummyDate.getTime()){   //rough check to ensure start date
                                                            //isn't in the past - precise enough
                                                            //for application's needs
             this.startDate = newStartDate; 
        }
        if(this.startDate.getTime() >= this.endDate.getTime()){ //shifts endDate 1 hour ahead of startDate if the new startDate
                                                                //is higher
            this.endDate.setTime(this.startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
        }
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date newEndDate){
        Date dummyDate = new Date();
        if(newEndDate.getTime() > dummyDate.getTime() && this.startDate.getTime() < newEndDate.getTime()){
                                                            //rough check to ensure end date
                                                            //isn't in the past or before start date - precise enough
                                                            //for application's needs
             this.endDate = newEndDate; 
        }
    }

    public void setDescription(String newDescription){
        this.description = newDescription;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }

    public void addManager(String newManager){
        //this.activityManagers.add(newManager);

    }

    /**
     * Returns how long the Activity will take.
     * @return Activity duration in hours.
     */
    public long getDuration(){  //returns how long the activity will take in hours.
        return this.duration;
    }

    /**
     * Saves Activity data to database
     */
    public void commitChanges(){
        MySqlDriver.saveObject(this);
    }

    public void loadData(int activityToLoadId){ //loads data of activity with name activityToLoadName from database
        this.id = activityToLoadId;
        MySqlDriver.loadObjectWithId(this, activityToLoadId);
    }
}
```

Everything is very much work in progress so some of the methods are patchwork, but I believe the problem lies in the way I mapped the ElementCollection.

As you can see, nowhere do I mention the column "activities_Id" that it is so adamantly looking for and the code that is trying to load it is nothing more than a session.get() and hibernate.initialize():

```
for(Integer projId : this.myProjectIds){
    try{
        Session newSession = Start.getFactory().getCurrentSession();
        newSession.beginTransaction();
        Project dummyProject = (Project) newSession.get(Project.class, projId);
        Hibernate.initialize(dummyProject.getActivities());
        this.myProjects.add(dummyProject);
        newSession.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!

-update-
I tried using OneToMany as suggested but I still get similar complaints about columns that I never mentioned not existing. This is what I have now in the Project class (instead of the elementcollection):

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Activity> activities;
```

and this is what I have in the Activities class (instead of the parent id int):

```
@ManyToOne
private Project parent;
```

The error I get now is even more confusing:

```
Hibernate: select activities0_.Project_Project_Id as Project_1_2_0_, activities0_.activities_Id as activiti2_2_0_, activity1_.Id as Id1_0_1_, activity1_.Description as Descript2_0_1_, activity1_.Duration as Duration3_0_1_, activity1_.End_Date as End_Date4_0_1_, activity1_.Name as Name5_0_1_, activity1_.parent_Project_Id as parent_P7_0_1_, activity1_.Start_Date as Start_Da6_0_1_, project2_.Project_Id as Project_1_1_2_, project2_.Name as Name2_1_2_, project2_.Owner_Id as Owner_Id3_1_2_ from Projects_Activities activities0_ inner join Activities activity1_ on activities0_.activities_Id=activity1_.Id left outer join Projects project2_ on activity1_.parent_Project_Id=project2_.Project_Id where activities0_.Project_Project_Id=?
15:54:02.463 [qtp94264799-20] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1146, SQLState: 42S02
15:54:02.464 [qtp94264799-20] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Table 'Project32.Projects_Activities' doesn't exist
```

Because it just seems to be making up column names. Maybe I'm missing something in the mysql table, I have a reference between a "Project_Id" column in Activities and the primary key with the same name in the Projects table.

Comment: ElementCollection is not what you should use here. Activity is an entity. For associations between entities, use OneToMany, OneToOne, ManyToOne or ManyToMany. ElementCollection is for collections of basic types, or embeddables.

Comment: I tried that (and now updated the question), I still have a similar issue

Comment: never mind, I found the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I wasn't using the annotations properly as I suspected, to fix the problem I had to specify the @JoinColumn in both the project and the activity (and make activity serializable, which I forgot to do initially). Now the classes are as follows:
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Activities")
    public class Activity implements java.io.Serializable{

```
    private static final long minDateDiff = 3600000;    //1H in milliseconds

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="Name")
    private String name;    //using same name for activities in same project not supported.
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;
    @Column(name="Start_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name="End_Date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date endDate;
    @Column(name="Duration")
    private long duration;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="Project_Id")
    private Project parent;


    public Activity(){

    }
    /**
     * Activity constructor, automatically sets default start and end date.
     * @param newName Name of the new activity
     * @param parent id of parent project
     */
    public Activity(String newName, int parentId){
        this.parent = new Project(parentId);
        this.name = newName;
        this.startDate = new Date();    //start date by default is creation time
        this.endDate = new Date();
        this.endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() + Activity.minDateDiff);   //end date by default is 1 hour ahead of start date
        this.description = new String();
        this.getDateDiff(startDate, endDate, TimeUnit.HOURS);   //set default duration
    }

    public void getDateDiff(Date date1, Date date2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {    //converts difference between dates from 
                                                                                //milliseconds to given time unit
                                                                            //credit to Sebastien Lorber (from StackOverflow)
        long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        this.duration=timeUnit.convert(diffInMillies,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void setName(String newName){
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date newStartDate){
        Date dummyDate = new Date();
        if(newStartDate.getTime() > dummyDate.getTime()){   //rough check to ensure start date
                                                            //isn't in the past - precise enough
                                                            //for application's needs
             this.startDate = newStartDate; 
        }
        if(this.startDate.getTime() >= this.endDate.getTime()){ //shifts endDate 1 hour ahead of startDate if the new startDate
                                                                //is higher
            this.endDate.setTime(this.startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
        }
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date newEndDate){
        Date dummyDate = new Date();
        if(newEndDate.getTime() > dummyDate.getTime() && this.startDate.getTime() < newEndDate.getTime()){
                                                            //rough check to ensure end date
                                                            //isn't in the past or before start date - precise enough
                                                            //for application's needs
             this.endDate = newEndDate; 
        }
    }

    public void setDescription(String newDescription){
        this.description = newDescription;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return this.description;
    }

    public void addManager(String newManager){
        //this.activityManagers.add(newManager);

    }

    /**
     * Returns how long the Activity will take.
     * @return Activity duration in hours.
     */
    public long getDuration(){  //returns how long the activity will take in hours.
        return this.duration;
    }

    /**
     * Saves Activity data to database
     */
    public void commitChanges(){
        MySqlDriver.saveObject(this);
    }

    public void loadData(int activityToLoadId){ //loads data of activity with name activityToLoadName from database
        this.id = activityToLoadId;
        MySqlDriver.loadObjectWithId(this, activityToLoadId);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Projects")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5115375190980452672L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Project_Id")
    private int id; // this should be set once on creation and never touched
                    // again as it identifies the project uniquely
    @Column(name = "Owner_Id")
    private int ownerId;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
//  @ElementCollection
//  @CollectionTable(name="Activities", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="Project_Id"))
//  @Column(name="Activity")
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="Project_Id")
    private List<Activity> activities;

    public Project(){

    }
    /**
     * Constructor to load existing project
     * @param idToLoad id of the project to load
     */
    public Project(int idToLoad) { 
//      MySqlDriver.loadObjectWithId(this, idToLoad);
        org.hibernate.Session session;
        try{
            session=Start.getFactory().getCurrentSession();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not load project.");
            System.out.println("Error while creating mysql session: "+e);
            return;
        }
        try{
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.load(this, idToLoad);
            this.activities.size();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Could not load project.");
            System.out.println("Error while committing changes: "+e);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates new project
     * @param newName name of the new project
     * @param newId id of the new project
     */
    public Project(String newName, int owner_Id) { // on creation a project
                                                        // only has a name and a
                                                        // unique id
        this.name = newName;
        this.ownerId = owner_Id;
        this.activities = null;
    }

    public void addActivity(String activityName) { // add new activity to the
                                                    // project with given
                                                    // attributes
        Activity newActivity = new Activity(activityName, this.id);
        this.activities.add(newActivity);
    }

    public void setName(String newName) { // change project name
        this.name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() { // return project name
        return this.name;
    }

    public List<Activity> getActivities(){
        return this.activities;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void commitChanges() {
        for (Activity act : this.activities)
            act.commitChanges(); // commit changes made to all activities in the
                                    // project
        MySqlDriver.saveObject(this);
    }

    public void deleteProject() {
        MySqlDriver.deleteObject(this);
    }

    public Activity selectActivity(String activityName) {
        for (Activity act : activities) { // cycle through activities and return
                                            // the one with the given name
            if (act.getName().equals(activityName))
                return act;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void deleteActivity(String deleteMeName) {
        for (Activity act : activities) { // cycle through activities and delete
                                            // the one with the given name
            if (act.getName().equals(deleteMeName)) {
                MySqlDriver.deleteObject(act);
                activities.remove(act);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void grantAccessToProject(String otherUser) {
        // grants permission to view and modify project database to user
        // otherUser
    }
}
```